# How do I set up Google Voice as the provider for an unactivated phone?

Tags: google-voice, voip

I've got this Droid X, it's not activated, and I'd like to use Google Voice as the provider (this means it will be Wi-Fi only; that's OK.)

Problem is, Google Voice needs the phone to have a number before it will let me use it as the provider. I already have a Google voice number set up, but I can't figure out what to do next.

What I'm envisioning is:

- The phone's dialer will make the calls through Google Voice (absolutely essential)
- Voicemails will work (would be very nice)
- I can text from the native texter (not critical at all)

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the free version of '**GrooVe IP Lite**' in the Play Store. The Free version utilizes Google Voice over WiFi only, but that's all you're asking for so you should be golden.

Comment: Thanks! Would be better if I didn't have to deal with Ads, but this looks like it's what I'm looking for. Will accept the answer once I finish a test call.

Comment: Perfect! It worked! I'd prefer ad-free, with the native dialer, but those cost money, and the free version works. :)

Comment: [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/en/android-about). :-)